# Why do I get 'Event loop is closed' in async code?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I always see some unexpected behavior when I use async code in python. For example I get a lot of `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed` after running this simple code. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```py
from asyncio import run, wait
from datetime import datetime

import aiohttp

url = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&tag=cat"

start = datetime.now()


async def load(i):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            pass
    print("Downloaded", i + 1, datetime.now() - start)


async def main():
    reqs = []
    for i in range(100):
        reqs.append(load(i))
    await wait(reqs)


run(main())
```

Comment: The code itself works for me. Do you get this code when executing this script or when doing something else with it?

Comment: That the whole code without any changes. It's works for me too, but I get errors after code is done running. I'm running it on Windows